# Implementing a shell: wrong argument in execvp()

Tags: c, linux, shell, pointers, execvp

Recently, I am trying to make good practice on C now I come to a command execution.
It tells me that I should us `char**`? But am I have some concept wrong.

Please help me.
Code is here

```
int excution(int cnt, char token[][BUFSIZE],int *t_token)
{
    setenv ("PATH", "/bin:/bin/usr:", 1);
    //printf("%s",getenv("PATH")); // check environement
    const char *b_cd="cd";
    const char *b_exit="exit";
    const char *b_fg="fg";
    const char *b_jobs="jobs";
    int  i,j,k;
    //STEP 9:excute normal commanand
    char args[cnt][BUFSIZE];
    for(i=0;i<MAXARG;i++)
    {
        if(t_token[i]==COMMAND)
        {
            strcpy(args[0],token[i]); // copy 1st ARG
            j=1;
            while(t_token[i+1]==ARG)  
            {
                strcpy(args[j],token[i+1]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
            printf("%s\n", args[k]);
            }
            execvp (args[0], args);
        }
    }
```

It gives me warning in compilation. But it gives segmentation fault if I change 2D array to a `char**`....

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execvp’ from incompatible pointer type
>   [enabled by default] /usr/include/unistd.h:579:12: note: expected
>   ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[256]’

Comment: The segfault must be happening because you did something *else* wrong there. See this question: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/51468/ -- and please show your failing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm just old, but when I see ***char var[X][Y]*** I think the compiler is going to allocate a chunk of memory of ***sizeof(char)*X*Y*** and then ***var[i]*** will be equal to ***var+(i*Y*(sizeof(char)))***.  As long as everybody knows what X & Y are, all is cool. But ***execvp()*** doesn't know your X & Y sizes.

In contrast, ***char * var[X]*** will give me an array of X pointers each ***sizeof(char*)***, or a blob of memory of ***sizeof(char*)*X***.

Now char's are generally 1 byte.  ***char**** is generally 4 or 8 bytes, but can vary depending on your system.

So ***char * var[X]*** might be a chunk of memory ***X*8*** bytes in size, and anyone receiving ***var*** as an argument would know how to access each ***char**** pointer in that array as pointer sizes are well known by the compiler and it's just a standard offset.

On the other hand, anyone receiving ***char var[X][Y]*** is going to be really confused.  There's no way to tell where one argument ends and another begins in that giant chunk of memory.

Long story short:  Use ***char * args[SIZE];***, use ***arg[i] = "command"*** or ***arg[i] = token[j]***, and learn about pointers.

p.s.  ***char***** is a pointer to a pointer to char.  (It's, say, 8 bytes that points to another memory address of 8 bytes of data that contains the memory address of a char (1-byte) value.  This makes more sense when we talk about storing strings as null-terminated (char(0)) arrays of characters - e.g. sequentially stored characters, so if we know the address of the first character in the string we can just increment the pointer to get the next character until we hit zero, the null character '\0'.)

It's similar to, but not quite the same as an array of pointers to char.  (Which is, say, 8 bytes that points to a memory address containing at least 8 bytes of data, perhaps N*8 bytes of sequential memory addresses (pointers).  Again, just like with the sequential char array, we can have an array of ***char****, one stored after the other in memory.)

It would be more accurate to say a ***char***** is roughly equal to a ***char*[N]***, only the ***char***** doesn't allocate any memory for the internal ***char**** pointers whereas ***char*[N]*** does - it allocate space for N ***char**** pointers.

When receiving an array of pointers to char (***char*[]***), you can declare it as a pointer to a pointer to char (***char*****) and still iterate through the array.  You just need to have the right underlying block of memory (data) located (passed in) where that pointer points to.